# Regular expression for input which should accept only decimals

Tags: javascript, string

I have an input which should accept only decimals. But it should be in the number range 38-41.

For example, *38.456546545*, *39.4564*, *40.12321*, or *41.87897*. It should accept only these type decimals, not like this: 5.787 or 0.4454 or *-32.4546*.

Comment: Why do you need regex? Comparison operators and type conversions exist.

Comment: Regex can solve this, but it's not a good tool, especially when you have access to JS/TS.

Comment: Re *"number range 38-41"*: There is always the question of boundaries. Inclusive? Exclusive? Which ones?

Comment: What if the number is exactly 40? Is 40 not allowed, but 40.0 allowed?

Comment: it should be included between 38-41

Comment: 38.0 - 41.0 is `(?:3[89]|40)\.\d|41\.0`

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I completely agree that usage of regex here unjustified.

If you don't know how make such a validation in js/ts, you better ask it than regex for this case.

That being said, if you missed some information in you question, and there is absolutely zero chance to make validation without regex you can use this:

```
^(?:3[89]|4[01])(?:\.\d*)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

*Note - Suggest that the `regex` tag be added back*
*If you don't need a regex then make your question about something else*

Most languages can convert an int to a float and visa-versa.
So converting string data to a numeric type requires the string to be parsed.
Like entered text literals in source code.
If a float is required a decimal point is inserted in the literal.

If designing a numeric input field on a form, the textual form of data that is allowed is what occurs.

The question says *Regular Expression* needed.
Like hundreds of identical type questions on SO, each uniquely differing in design,
this is another.

The range ***38.0 - 41.0***

```
^(?:(?:3[89]|40)\.\d*|41\.0*)$
```

Explained

```
 ^             # Begin string
 (?:
                  #  38.0  to  40.9
    (?:
       3 [89] 
     | 40
    )
    \. 
    \d* 
  | 
                  #  41.0
    41 \. 
    0*
 )
 $             # End string
```